# Dependency of autowire failes

Tags: java, spring

```
public class PartnershipMaintenanceFunction
{
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( PartnershipMaintenanceFunction.class );

    @Autowired
    PartnershipMaintenanceController partnershipMaintenanceServiceController;

    public RetrievePartnershipResponse retrievePartnership( Message<RetrievePartnershipRequest> messageRequest )
    {
        RetrievePartnershipRequest retrievePartnershipRequest = messageRequest.getPayload();

        MessageHeaders header = messageRequest.getHeaders();

        return partnershipMaintenanceServiceController.retrievePartnership( retrievePartnershipRequest );

    }

}
```

controller class

```
@RestController
@Api( "Partnership Maintainence" )
public class PartnershipMaintenanceController
{
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( PartnershipMaintenanceController.class );

    @Autowired
    PartnershipService partnershipService;

    public void setPartnershipService( PartnershipService partnershipService )
    {
        this.partnershipService = partnershipService;
    }


    @GET
    @Path( "/retrievePartnershipRequest" )
    @ApiOperation( "Retrieve Partnership" )
    public RetrievePartnershipResponse retrievePartnership( RetrievePartnershipRequest request )
    {
        return partnershipService.retrievePartnership( request );

    }
}



public class PartnershipMaintenanceFunction
{
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( PartnershipMaintenanceFunction.class );

    @Autowired
    PartnershipMaintenanceController partnershipMaintenanceServiceController;


}
```

controller class

```
@RestController
@Api( "Partnership Maintainence" )
public class PartnershipMaintenanceController
{
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( PartnershipMaintenanceController.class );

    @Autowired
    PartnershipService partnershipService;

    public void setPartnershipService( PartnershipService partnershipService )
    {
        this.partnershipService = partnershipService;
    }
```

> Error creating bean with name 'partnershipMaintenanceController':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field:
>   com.cgi.bkifs.bso.prime.partnership.maintainence.service.PartnershipService
>   com.cgi.bkifs.rest.service.controller.PartnershipMaintenanceController.partnershipService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.cgi.bkifs.bso.prime.partnership.maintainence.service.PartnershipService]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: Can anyoone please guide me.....

Comment: Is there PartnershipService class in your classpath?

Comment: There is no Spring bean of type PartnershipService. That's what the error is telling you. Show us why you think there is one.

Comment: Ensure you have a `PartnershipService` class that's Spring managed. Also your `PartnershipMaintenanceFunction` should be annotated with `@Component` or `@Service`

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot to making `PartnershipService` as Spring Bean.

```
   @Component
   public class PartnershipService{}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the bean ( PartnershipService ) is Normal bean then you can use @Component
If the bean (PartnershipService  ) is service bean ( Service layer ) then you can use @service

> Information about @Component, @Service, @Controller, and @Repository
>   annotation do in Spring Framework:
>  @Component is a generic stereotype
>   for any Spring-managed component or bean. 
>  @Repository is a stereotype
>   for the persistence layer.
>  @Service is a stereotype for the service
>   layer.
>  @Controller is a stereotype for the presentation layer
>   (spring-MVC).

Comment: Try to scan your beans with Component Scan  by xml or autowired.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages says:

> Could not autowire field:
>   com.cgi.bkifs.bso.prime.partnership.maintainence.service.PartnershipService

Assuming that you already declared a class `PartnershipService` and it has the `@Service` annotation it is likely that you did not define the component scan.

Either add

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.cgi.bkifs.bso.prime.partnership")` or in older versions use the xml file to define the scope of component scan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <context:component-scan base-package="com.cgi.bkifs.bso.prime.partnership"/>

</beans>
```